# PHP Contact Form not triggering email

Tags: php, contact-form

The following php contact form is not working for me. Could you please help me to  fix the error.
After submitting the form, there is no email triggered. I am not sure, what is wrong. The following php contact form is not working for me. Could you please help me to  fix the error.

```css
<?php
ob_start();
if(isset($_POST['your-name'])){
 $to = "info@freshpotsolutions.com";
 $from = $_POST['your-name'].'<'.$_POST["email"].'>';
 $subject = "Enquiry Form";
 
 $message= '<html>
    <body bgcolor="#EBEBEB" style="font-family:Roboto,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"> 
   <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">
   <tr>
   <td colspan="3" align="left"><h3>Booker Information</h3></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="3"> &nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td width="160" > Name</td><td width="15">:</td><td>'.$_POST["your-name"].'</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
            <td>Email</td><td>:</td><td>'.$_POST["your-email"].'</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
            <td>Website</td><td>:</td><td>'.$_POST["tel-681"].'</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
            <td>Message</td><td>:</td><td>'.$_POST["your-message"].'</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </body>
   </html>';
  //
  $headers  = "MIME-Version:1.0 \r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
  $headers  .= "From: $from\r\n";
  if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
     //session_destroy();
     header('Location:enquiry.html?message=success');
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="messageForm.php" class="wpcf7-form" method="post" novalidate>

        <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input class=
        "wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required floatlabel"
        name="your-name" placeholder="Name" size="40" type="text"></span>
        </p>
        <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input class=
        "wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email floatlabel"
        name="your-email" placeholder="Email" size="40" type="email"></span>
        </p>
        <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap tel-681"><input class=
        "wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-tel floatlabel"
        name="tel-681" placeholder="Phone" size="40" type="tel"></span>
        </p>
        <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message">
        <textarea class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea floatlabel" cols=
        "40" name="your-message" placeholder="Message" rows="10">
</textarea></span>
        </p>
        <p data-scrollreveal="enter bottom over 1s after 1s and move 50px">
        <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit get-in-touch-submit-btn"
        type="submit" value="Send">
        </p>
        <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Are you testing this on your machine or server ?

Comment: whats the problem you find

Comment: Name of the email field is `your-email` while you are using `email` only

Comment: I will also share the website address: rahtik.ae/test5 The form is under the div section <get-in-touch>

Comment: @user3287040 It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
$from = $_POST['your-name'].'<'.$_POST["email"].'>';
```

to

```
$from = $_POST['your-name'].'<'.$_POST["your-email"].'>';
```

Comment: No, this didnt fix the issue. It still does not trigger any email.

Comment: I will also share the website address: http://rahtik.ae/test5/ The form is under the div section <get-in-touch>

Comment: @josh as your question is `PHP Contact Form not triggering email` so i made some changes you have check weather it works or not

Comment: I changed the code as per your first comment, but it did not resolve the issue.